How to remove duplicate outputs in an if statement ps script
I am using a script that lists VMs that are Running, and have an Agent Status as Not Ready.
If the script doesn't have any VMs matching those conditions, it will produce no output.
Here is the script:
Set-AzContext -Subscription "MySub"
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$output = @()
$VMs_running = Get-AzVM  -status | ?{$_.PowerState -eq 'VM running'}


foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
    $VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status
    
    $Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
    $Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
    $Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
    $Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
    $Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
    if ($Row.VMAgent_Status -ne "Ready"){
      $output += $Row
    }
}

$output

I want to add in that if the output is null, then print "All VMs are Ready".
At the moment when I add this in, I get duplicate outputs (matching the number of VMs that exist as expected):
foreach($VM in $VMs_running)
{
    $VM_status = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status
    
    $Row = "" | select Name, ResourceGroupName, VMAgent_Status, VMAgent_Version
    $Row.Name = $VM_status.Name
    $Row.ResourceGroupName = $VM_status.ResourceGroupName
    $Row.VMAgent_Status = $VM_status.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus
    $Row.VMAgent_Version = $VM_status.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion
    if ($Row.VMAgent_Status -ne "Ready"){
      $output += $Row
    }
    Else
    {
    $VMsReady = Write-Host "All VMs are Ready"
    $output | Group-Object | Where-Object Count -gt 1 | Select-Object $VMsReady
    }
}

$output

The output is:
All VMs are Ready
All VMs are Ready
All VMs are Ready
All VMs are Ready
All VMs are Ready

How do I get just one output?

The else condition should be actually outside the loop. First check if there are VMs meeting the condition VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus -ne 'Ready' and then, after looping over all, you can check if there was $output:
$output = foreach ($VM in $VMs_running) {
    Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Status |
        Where-Object { $_.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus -ne 'Ready' } |
        Select-Object @(
            'Name'
            'ResourceGroupName'
            @{ N = 'VMAgent_Status'; E = { $_.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus } }
            @{ N = 'VMAgent_Version'; E = { $_.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion } })
}

if (-not $output) {
    Write-Host 'All VMs are Ready'
}
else {
    $output
}

Possibly, the subsequent call to Get-AzVM inside the foreach could be simply removed by combining both conditions:
Set-AzContext -Subscription 'MySub'
$WarningPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$output = Get-AzVM -Status |
    Where-Object { $_.PowerState -eq 'VM running' } |
    Where-Object { $_.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus -ne 'Ready' } |
    Select-Object @(
        'Name'
        'ResourceGroupName'
        @{ N = 'VMAgent_Status'; E = { $_.VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus } }
        @{ N = 'VMAgent_Version'; E = { $_.VMAgent.VmAgentVersion } })

if (-not $output) {
    Write-Host 'All VMs are Ready'
}
else {
    $output
}


That unfortunately doesn't work. It outputs VMs that have Agent Status as Ready.
Based on your statement, let me see if I can create the if and else statement outside of the original code I presented.

@JonH Which of the snippets is the one not working? the first one which starts with $output = foreach ($VM in $VMs_running) { has no logical difference than the one you have in your question. $output should have only VMs with .VMAgent.Statuses.DisplayStatus not equal to Ready. Even if you observe the answer provided by a different user in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78335980/15339544 it's exactly the same answer I'm giving here.
